# Modules give the error Page not found. Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I am using the latest version of opencart 2.3.0.2. I downloaded the zipped package of opencart and installed it on my live server. Now when I click on Modules and Shipping etc (exclusive of Extensions Installer and Modifications) I got Page not found error every time. I am getting this error on the following pages "Modules, Shipping, Payments, Order Totals and Feeds".

Help me i am stuck in this issue.

Comment: I think, it is file missing error. maybe, Not all files in your server have been uploaded properly. please try again upload OpeCart source file. & the check it.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that somehow the files in `upload/admin/controller/extension/extension` have been damaged or not properly uploaded.  Try uploading them again from a fresh download.